# Как переменной присвоить произвольное поле?

Tags: php, wordpress, acf

Возможно, заголовок не совсем корректный.

В WordPress реализую вывод записей по рубрикам.

Хочу, чтобы рубрика указывалась через админку, через плагин произвольных полей "advanced custom fields"

```
<?php
$id=2;// ID заданной рубрики которое хочется чтобы заполнялась через админку
$n=3;   
$recent = new WP_Query("cat=$id&showposts=$n");
while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();
?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Использую этот код.

Хочу вместо "2" ($id=2;), присвоить произвольное поле.

С помощью плагина, произвольное поле, которое задается через админку при редактирования поста, выводится следующим кодом

```
<?php the_field('рубрика'); ?>
```

В php не разбираюсь, поэтому пробовал таким способом, который не работает.

```
$id=the_field('рубрика');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция `the_field()` выводит на экран. Чтобы получить значение переменной, вам нужно сделать так:

```
$id=get_field('рубрика');
```